# AWS SQL Server Standard Edition Storage Size downgrade using Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, restore, snapshot

I am looking at downgrading the Storage Size from 100GiB to 20GiB. Before doing that I have taken a Snapshot to avoid data loss. This exercise is mainly due to the fact that the RDS storage was over estimated while the actual data when checked via cloud watch at any time is less than 10GiB.
So my task is to use the Snapshot taken from the 100GiB DB and restore it to a DB that is at a size of 20GiB.
Is this possible or any work around to fit in a bigger snapshot to a DB with reduced storage size?
While via console it is NOT possible, as it will not allow less than 100GiB based on the snapshot, when trying via Terraform as well will give an error like

> 16:09:30  │ Error: updating RDS DB Instance (dbSmall): InvalidParameterCombination: Invalid storage size for engine name sqlserver-se and storage type gp3: 20
> 16:09:30  │     status code: 400, request id: dd14f7c6-7e34-6703-81ac-5686007fb0ba

I believe the scenario I am trying to achieve is valid, when we figure out we have an underused storage we always attempt to downgrade but still would like to retain the data.

Any one encountered similar issue and managed to downgrade with a bigger snapshot storage size?

Thank you

Comment: An RDS Snapshot is backing up the entire EBS volume that forms your RDS instance, file system and all, as opposed to just backing up a single database within that instance. Have you considered just doing a [full backup of the database to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) and restoring it to a new instance?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Thank you for your thoghts. I have not yet considered on the backup of the DB to S3. Will give a go.